# How to split the slider setting for each slide CSS

Tags: html, css

I have picture slider Code in HTML/CSS, which is created for the whole slider. So problem which is being raised is, I am unable to set the image for each slider separately. Now there is a single image which is set for the each slider. But i want to set separate image for each slider. Here is the code.

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>It’s Time to <br><span>Get back to school</span></h2>
                    <a href="#">Check out our new programs</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / content -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>It’s Time to <br><span>Get back to school</span></h2>
                    <a href="#">Check out our new programs</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / content -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>It’s Time to <br><span>Get back to school</span></h2>
                    <a href="#">Check out our new programs</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / content -->
        </li>

    </ul>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.slider {
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 94px;
}

.slider .bxslider li {
    background: url(../images/pic_slide.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
}


.slider .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 122px 15px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child),

```
.slider {
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 94px;
}

.slider .bxslider li {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
}
.slider .bxslider li:nth-child(1) {
    background: url(../images/pic_slide.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.slider .bxslider li:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(../images/pic_slide2.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.slider .bxslider li:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(../images/pic_slide3.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.slider .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 122px 15px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.How i will incorporate these setting HTML code.?

Comment: You don't need to do Anything in HTML, `nth-child` that check `<li>` by number, it means: `nth-child(1)` looking for first `<li>` in yours`.boxslider` class, and `nth-child(2)` looking for second `<li>` in your `.boxslider` etc..., so you don't need to update HTML